# Issue passing in custom parameters to Twilio API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am attempting to build out a process that will do the following:

1. New contact lands in my CRM (Podio)
2. The CRM is triggered to send a POST containing a *custom parameter* to Twilio which will then initiate a flow
3. The Twilio flow will call my cell and prompt me to connect to the new contact
4. Once I press 1, it will take the *custom parameter* (new contact's phone number) and connect
   me to them.

So far, I have been able to get 1-3 with no problem.

However, according to the the API documentation from Twilio I should be able to pass a 3rd parameter in the JSON body of my HTTP request containing custom "Parameters". When I attempt this the parameters aren't showing in the Twilio studio logs and thus I am unable to connect the call to the new lead.

This is the JSON body I am sending over to my Twilio Flow's API

```
{
    "To": "+1xxxxxxxxx1",
    "From": "+1xxxxxxxxx2",
    "Parameters": {
        "name": "example name",
        "prospectphone": "+1xxxxxxxxx3"
    }
}
```

When I view the logs in Twilio this is what I received.

```
{
  "contact": {
    "channel": {
      "address": "+1xxxxxxxxx2"
    }
  },
  "trigger": {
    "request": {
      "from": "+1xxxxxxxxx2",
      "to": "+1xxxxxxxxx1",
      "parameters": {}
    }
  },
  "widgets": {},
  "flow": {
    "flow_sid": "FW936f72c0eb8d3945d0d55c62465e37a8",
    "data": {},
    "channel": {
      "address": "+1xxxxxxxxx2"
    },
    "sid": "FN955cdb12827f84c8af8fc9b5264e5a28"
  }
}
```

I really can't figure out what I'm missing here? Has anyone run into this before? Is this something you can only do if you're using the SDK or does the additional parameter need to be passed in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

It should be sent `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

From the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution):

"Note: the JSON value must explicitly be passed as a string, not as a hash object. Depending on your particular HTTP library, you may need to add quotes or URL encode the JSON string."

[Trigger a Twilio Studio Flow Execution via the REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Is that something I pass in on the header? I dont know if the HTTP request function in podio supports that, I may need to try another path. Could I possibly achieve the same thing using urlencode() in php (which podio supports).

As a side note, it is accepting the To and From values with no problem which are in the same JSON.